# Trim beginning of a text file

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file with unexpected spaces at the beginning and would like to trim the beginning and save it. How can I do it?

I have tried a very simple example I have found on the internet but it erases the file instead:

```bsh
cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default| sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' > /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Comment: Try without redirecting the file onto itself: `cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' > test` and if this gives a better result consider using the `--in-place` option to make changes insitu. Or you can do some fast work with a temp file. If it works I can write a formal answer...

Answer (score 1):

This:

```bsh
cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default| sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' > /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

truncates the file because the `>` redirection is resolved first; i.e. the file is truncated before `cat` and `sed` are run (and `cat` reads an empty file).

Also the command strips leading spaces **and tabulations**.

If that's what you want, just use the in place option of `sed` (and to drop the useless `cat`):

```bsh
sed -ie 's/^[ \t]*//' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

If you want to remove only leading spaces, use this command instead:

```bsh
sed -ie 's/^ *//' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

---

Also it looks like you want to process only the first line.

If that's the case, prepend a `1` to the `s` command; i.e.:

```
sed -ie '1s/^[ \t]*//' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

to strip leading spaces and tabulations from the first line and

```
sed -ie '1s/^ *//' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

to remove only leading spaces from the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
cat 1.txt | sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//' | sed '/^$/d' > 2.txt
```

#### Explanation

1. `cat 1.txt` - loads the file content as input
2. `sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//'` - removes empty spaces from both sides of the file. Beginning or trailing.
3. `sed '/^$/d'` - removes empty lines (in case left by the above command)
4. `> 2.txt` - saves the result into a new file.

In case you don't want to remove the empty lines, skip step three. In which case your command becomes:

```
cat 1.txt | sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//' > 2.txt
```

#### Example

Input text (as image, dots show spaces):

[image]

Output text (as image, No dots and empty lines removed):

[image]

### EDIT

The above explanation empties a file if redirected onto itself as shown below:

```
cat 1.txt | sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//' | sed '/^$/d' > 1.txt
```

To handle this and make sure the content is re-written into the file, we just have to echo the output out as in the command below:

```
echo | cat 1.txt | sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//' | sed '/^$/d' > 1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but again, its works when i save into a different file, but when i try to override existing it empty after the command you mention

Comment: @ArkadyB I have edited the answer to handle the issue of the file being emptied when redirected onto itself.

Comment: still this line erases my file: echo | cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default | sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//' > /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

Comment: This has a high chance of failing; commands in pipes are run asynchronously. Often they end up running left-to-right, but that's not always the case; if the pipe containing the `>` redirection happens to run first, the file is truncated, and `cat` won't be able to read it. Try running the command say 20 times in a loop; most likely you'll end up with an empty file. When reading and writing to the same file, the safest solution is using `sponge` to output to the file (or reading the file in a command substitution, which is always run first, but that's not too efficient for large files).

Comment: @kos Pipes are run async? I never knew that, have always thought it is sync...you know, output of one command is input of another.

Comment: The output *flow* is indeed synchronous and flows left to right, but the commands are not necessarily run in the same order; try for example `for ((i=0; i<20; i++)); do echo foo >baz | echo bar >baz; cat baz; done`. I think Zsh takes care of that, because I can't reproduce the same in Zsh, but in Bash that's a problem.

Comment: Yeah, seen it. This needs more research and (maybe) reporting as a bug. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, then different approach.. how would i reuse sed to remove everything before first occurence of server work (the work itself shoudl remain)...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Python (both Python 2 or Python 3) for the job:

```
python -c 'import sys; print("".join((str(line).lstrip(" ") for line in sys.stdin)))' <INPUTFILE >OUTPUTFILE
```

What this command does:

- `python -c '...'` or `python3 -c '...'`:
  Start the Python (2 or 3) interpreter and let it run the commands in the quotes.
- `import sys; print("".join((str(line).lstrip(" ") for line in sys.stdin)))`:
  This is a little Python script compressed to one single line that reads everything from STDIN (standard input stream) and prints it back to STDOUT (standard output stream) after having removed all whitespace characters (including spaces, tabs, etc.) from the beginning of each line. It will continue reading until the stream ends, that means either until you manually type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> if STDIN is connected to the keyboard, or until all the data has passed through if STDIN is connected to a file or pipe.
- `<INPUTFILE`:
  This connects the file `INPUTFILE` (replace with appropriate file name) with the command's STDIN. If you omit this, the command will read from the keyboard input instead.
- `>OUTPUTFILE`:
  This connects the file `OUTPUTFILE` (replace with appropriate file name) with the command's STDOUT. If you omit this, the command will print its output to the terminal instead.

Please note that `INPUTFILE` and `OUTPUTFILE` may not be the same files in this case, as the used Bash output redirection is resolved first and overwrites the file before the script reads from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/^[ \t]*//|x' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close